# How to use a UserControl inside the EditTemplate of a ListVIew?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, listview, user-controls, webforms

Here is the situation:

- I have a `ListView` showing just a list of concatenated strings obtained from different field of the objects of the datasource.
- A `LinkButton` (with `CommandName="Edit"`) in each row
- Event handlers for `OnItemDataBound` and `OnItemEditing`
- A UserControl in `EditTemplate`.

Now the problem is, I don't know how to use `Bind` expression in the UserControl. I mean, how to populate this usercontrol when the linkbutton is clicked? (I tried capturing the control in the 
`OnItemEditing` handler. But `FindControl` returned `null`, as that handler is called *before* going to edit mode.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got an answer from asp.net forum. The solution is:

- Modify the UserControl so that, it supports DataBinding. To do that, implement the `DefaultBindingPropertyAttribute`. [Details here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171926%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    TheClass theControl = (TheClass)e.Item.FindControl("theControl)";
    theControl.someProperty = "bla bla bla";
}
```

Comment: Problem is, 'e.Item.FindControl("theControl)"' does not return the usercontrol (in the EditTemplate)